# Dynamically Check if Radio Button is Checked with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, radio-button

I'm trying to create a custom snippet for our website. I'm not the greatest with Jquery but know enough to at least get around. My dilemma right now is trying to have Jquery check if a radio group has an option checked and to then display the correct corresponding group for that option. Here is what I have currently:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Check if Oak is checked
    var $oakchecked = $("input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $oakactive = $(".b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if B. Maple is checked
    var $bmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $bmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Cherry is checked
    var $cherrychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $cherryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if QSWO is checked
    var $qswochecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $qswoactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if H. Maple is checked
    var $hmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $hmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Hickory is checked
    var $hickorychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains");
    var $hickoryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li");

    // Hide stains unless a wood is chosen
    var radio_buttons = $("input[name='tmcp_radio_0']");
    if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0){
       $(".stains-container").hide();
        } else if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 1 && /^Oak_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".oak-stains-div").show();
            $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
            $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 1 && /^Brown Maple_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
            $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 1 && /^Cherry_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
            $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 1 && /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
            $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
            $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 1 && /^Hard Maple_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
            $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 1 && /^Hickory_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
            $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
        }
    // Check if Oak is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Oak_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".oak-stains-div").show();
            $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
            $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        }  else {
            $(".oak-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if B. Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Brown Maple_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
            $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Cherry is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Cherry_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
            $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".cherry-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if QSWO is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
            $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
            $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".qswo-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hard Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hard Maple_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
            $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hickory is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hickory_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
            $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".hickory-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

My idea is to 1st check if that radio group is already selected and if so check which option is selected then display the correct section for it. If not, to hide it until an option is selected. Then if someone was to go and select a different option to go and display the correct group.

Currently the selecting a different group section is good. Probably could be done better but for now it works. My hang up is getting it to check if an option is already checked and to then show the correct group.

Any help on this would be amazing. If anyone has any ideas on how to get it working correctly I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks all!

Edit: If this helps I've [added the link to our staging site](https://amishdirectfurniture-staging.g3wenplb-liquidwebsites.com/shop/dining/table/trestle-table/abilene-dining-table/) of what I am working with. The idea is when a wood is select it will display the correct stains under "Finishing" for those woods. Right now I have the hide stains commented out under our "adf-scripts.js" file.

Comment: Please share the html as well to better understand what the current code is working with.

Comment: That would be smart. I added the link to our staging site that I am playing around with.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Array to write down every checkbox id checked (first you need to find a way to set an id to every option in your radio button).

And then in the case the checked function returns false, the checked radio button id is writhed in the array and if it returns true the checked radio button id is removed from the array.

That's the logic behind it. I tried and it worked for me many times.
Good work

Comment: That was my first thought. The issue is I'm trying to work around a plugin we use. Changing the options messes with that. I might have to brainstorm some more on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have many things of same type or belongs to a common parent you can interate over they.

Let's imagine a group of particular radios and i want check if at least one is checked or not (Very useful when you have non initialized radios and want prevent a blank submit to it).

```
<div>
    <label>My Radio1</label>
    <input type='radio' name="my-radio" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='my-radio1'>

    <label>My Radio2</label>
    <input type='radio' name="my-radio" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='my-radio2'>

    <label>My Radio3</label>
    <input type='radio' name="my-radio" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='my-radio3'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
</div>
```

```
// flag will tell to our promise if any radio 
//is checked if evaluated to 'true'
let flag = false;

//here you can also use '.some-class-of-radiogroup' as selector

//each iterator is a cool way to performe one to one verification on group of 
//inputs, elements....
// inside each callback you are in element's context so you can refers to it
// with $(this) and will assume current iteracted element

$("[name='my-radio']").each(function(){

    //check if current radio is checked or not
    flag = $(this).is(":checked"); // yeah only returns True or false
}).promise().done(function(){

    //above is an important thing to do '.promise().done...'
    //each is an asynchronous function so compare flag outside
    // may not work well but inside done's callback everything works well

    // here is where you decide wht to do.
    if(flag){
        alert("Some is checked")
    } else {
        alert("No radio are checked yet");
    } 
})
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm after. What is strange is even though the input is "check='checked'" the alert is mentioning nothing is checked.

Comment: Please explain that how your answer will help to solve the problem, and just dont give code only answer without context

Comment: I beg your pardon, there are a well explained answer right now

Comment: Thank you for the explained answer, @AloisoJunior. Not the best at writing in Jquery. Would it be possible to have the IF function check if the value matches as well? For example I'm trying to check if the button that is pre-checked is checked AND if it matches a value. When I go to use the following: `if(flag && /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val()) )` I get a syntax error the the "&&". I've trying searching on how to have a promise check the function plus another condition but can't find the answer. Have any suggestions?

Comment: @ADF can you provide your .html?

Comment: @AloisoJunior the area to see it best is through the staging site I am testing this at. You can [view it through this link](https://amishdirectfurniture-staging.g3wenplb-liquidwebsites.com/shop/dining/table/trestle-table/abilene-dining-table/). Right now I have under the options an option pre-checked. However I need it to then check if the value of that wood matches to the corresponding stains below. I have a file called "adf-scripts.js" that has the snippet in. At the moment the logic seems to be backwards. I want a section to show if that group has an option checked. At the moment it hides.